# Error during deploying lwc from vscode to org : Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier","PrivateName"]

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to build datatable to show Account details. Below are my components

```
public class getAccountsController {
     @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Account> getAccounts(Decimal latitude, Decimal longitude)
{
    List<Account> accounts = [ SELECT
                              id, name,geoAddress__c,DISTANCE( geoAddress__c, GEOLOCATION( :latitude, :longitude ), 'mi' ) dist
                              FROM
                              Account 
                              ORDER BY
                              DISTANCE( geoAddress__c, GEOLOCATION( :latitude, :longitude ), 'mi' ) asc
                              LIMIT 5];
    system.debug('accounts--'+accounts);
    
    return accounts;
        }
}
```

geo.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable data={accList} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

geo.js

```
import { LightningElement,track,api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/getAccountsController.getAccounts';
export default class Geo extends LightningElement {
    @track accList;
    lat = 80.0;
    long = 100.0;
    @track columns = [{
        label: 'Account name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Distance',
        fieldName: 'dist',
        type: 'Decimal',
        sortable: true
    }

];

@wire(getAccountList,{
    latitude:'$lat',
    longitude:'$long'
})
wireAccounts({
    data,error
}){
if(data)
{
    this.accList = data;
}
else if (error) {
   
}
}

}
```

when i try to deploy the lwc from vscode to org i get error :   **TypeError: LWC1007: /home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.17.9-232.0/geo.js: Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier","PrivateName"] but instead got "StringLiteral"**

Also when i remove wire method , the component deploys successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with property name `long`, it gives an error when marking that property as a dynamic and reactive with `$long`.

*Cause of error might be because long is a reserved word in JavaScript.*

After changing the property name, I am able to deploy:

```js
lat = 80.0;
longitude = 100.0;

@wire(getAccountList, {
    latitude: "$lat",
    longitude: "$longitude"
})
wireAccounts({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.accList = data;
    } else if (error) {
        // Note: always handle exception to show user when something went wrong
    }
}
```

---

If you still want to [use reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_word_usage), use a JavaScript object and attach them as property, that seems to be allowed:

```js
address = { lat: 80.0, long: 100.0 };

@wire(getAccountList, {
    latitude: "$address.lat",
    longitude: "$address.long"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this thing with `'$'` works but you should solve this using js variables as follows.

```
@wire(getAccountList,{
    latitude: this.lat,
    longitude: this.long
})
```

Comment: using this.lat and this.long the component gets deployed successfully but on load of component it is giving error as : Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')]